# How to return list of values based on a specified condition in EXCEL? - project dashboard

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am currently building a dashboard to track project status by individual business unit and am wondering if there is any way for excel to return a list of project names based on the business unit [example below].

[image]

Please share if you have any tips on this, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pre O365 versions you can use `INDEX`/`AGGREGATE`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(F:F,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($F$2:$F$7)/($E$2:$E$7=$B$1),ROW(A1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @basic, thanks for the tips! May I ask what is the 15;6 representing in your aggregate formula?

Comment: @Rosellx ```15``` - function type ```SMALL```, ```6``` - option ```Ignore error values```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Office365` then use `FILTER()` function.

```
=FILTER(F3:F6,E3:E6=B2)
```

[image]

Comment: What if I do not have office365?

Comment: Then you have to use combination of few others formula. I will post as I am writing now from mobile.